# Find the value of $k$ when $x=1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> The graph of the function with rule $\frac{k}{2(x^3+1)}$ has gradient 1 when $x=1$.Find the value of k 
>                     the answer is $\frac{-8}{3}$

I did it 
find derivative of
 $\frac{k}{2(x^3+1)}$
$2(3x^2)$
$6x^2$
sub $x=1$
$6(1)^2=6$
$\frac{k}{2(x^3+1)}$ 
$x=6$
$1=\frac{k}{12}$
$k=12$
still can't get 
$\frac{-8}{3}$ 
help me out thanks.

Comment: Your derivative **with respect to** $x$ is wrong.

Comment: edited mistake, still wrong?

Comment: You still haven't given the derivative with respect to $x$, you still seem to differentiate with respect to $k$, and that's where your trouble is starting...

Comment: edited, still wrong?

Comment: Well, if you don't get the answer -$\frac{8}{3}$, then it's going to be wrong, yes. I suggest you revise how to find the derivative of functions, e.g., how would you differentiate $y = \frac{1}{x}$ with respect to $x$? once you feel comfortable doing this, attempt the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you are having trouble finding

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{k}{2(x^3+1)}\right).$$

It's

$$\frac{k}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{d}{dx}(x^3+1)^{-1}\right) = \frac{k}{2} \cdot (-1) \cdot (x^3+1)^{-2} \cdot (3x^2) = \frac{-3kx^2}{2(x^3+1)^2}.$$

That's the correct way to find derivatives, or you could simply use the [quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule).

Now , its given that the value of derivative is 1 when x=1, so we have,

$\frac{-3k}{8}=1$ this gives $k=\frac{-8}{3}$

Comment: still $x=1$ is $\frac{-3k}{4}$ i can't get $-\frac{8}{3}$

Comment: @SbSangpi , hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the derivative of $\frac{k}{2(x^3 + 1)}$ with respect to $x$ first before you substitute in $x = 1$ and set the equation equal to 1.

Steps:

- Find the derivative of your function with respect to $x$ in order to find its gradient at $x$.
- Use the given values for $x$ and the gradient.
- Solve for $k$.

Comment: edited, still can't get answer! thx

Comment: @Sb Sangpi: Your derivative is wrong. Try writing your function as $y = k(2x^3 + 2)^{-1}$ and use the chain rule.